# Find the inverse of function

Tags: joint-distribution, copula

I have a two variable distribution function which I have to find it inverse. The expression is the following:

$H(s,t)=t\log(s) +t - t \log(t); \text{ if } s>t$

given: $v = t -t \log (t)$ and $u = s$

the idea is to find a function $C(u,v)$ given the functions above

Comment: A two-variable distribution function, by definition, maps $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$. As such, it cannot have an inverse (in the conventional mathematical sense).  What exactly do you mean by "inverse" then?

Comment: Yes, the only understandable version is to find the inverse of the transform of (s,t) into (s,H(s,t))...

Comment: You're simply doing a bivariate change of variable here. It looks like you're simply computing $C$ to me.

Comment: Hi thank you a lot for answering. I commited a mistake, I was trying to find the copula for the bivariate distribution above using the pseudo-inverse of the second expression, which is an univariate distribution function. I solved this obtaining the pseudo-inverse of F(t)=t−tlog(t)  using the Uniroot function. I will post how I did create the copula. Thank you again for your commitment.